# Add file name to top of each column (tab separated) for multiple files

Tags: linux, text

I have many files in a single directory, the first few are named:

1A_T
1B_T
2B
3_6A_T

Each file has three columns of data that are tab delimited.

I need to add the name of the file to the top of each column in the file, and do this for all files in the directory. Keeping everything tab delimited is crucial.

Simple suggestions? I've tried several approaches (I'm new to this) from the internet but can't get it to work properly.

Thanks for your help

Comment: So you want to duplicate the filename 3-times as the heading for each of the 3-columns contained in each file??? If so, `for i in *; do printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$i" "$i" "$i" > tempfile; cat "$i" >> tempfile; mv -f tempfile "$i"; done`

Comment: Thanks David, that worked perfectly. Absolute superstar!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command:

```
for f in `find . -type f`; do echo $f; sed -i.bak "1 i $f\t$f\t$f" $f; done
```

**just in case test it in a different directory before doing it on your working directory**.

**Explanations:**

- `find . -type f` will get all the files from your directory (and its sub dir) (run this command from the directory where you want to proceed or change `.` accordingly with the `PATH` to your **dir**)
- `for f in` will iterate on all your files you could also use `xargs` command
- `sed -i.bak "1 i $f\t$f\t$f" $f;` will take a backup of your file then edit it and add before the first line of your file the `filename\tfilename\tfilename`

**TESTED:**

[image]

**REMARK:**

beware of spaces in the filenames!

Last but not least, I have taken both of your points in the comment and you can use the following command in order to not have the `./` before the file name on the first line and to process files only in the working directory.

```
for f in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`; do echo `basename $f`; sed -i.bak "1 i `basename $f`\t`basename $f`\t`basename $f`" $f; done
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with `find`, but the "*single directory*" part of the question may pose problems if there are subdirectories present. A `-maxdepth 1` would resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks Allan! This worked except the ./ was included in the header of each column. I appreciate the explanation as well, it really helps.

I can easily move the files to a lower directory if there are issues. 

The solution by David was also good so the problem's solved.

Comment: @David nicely picked! :)

Comment: @Kelli Anderson: If you liked my answer or if it solved your issue you can vote up, or accept it as anwer! to give me some fame ;) ;) that's the principle of SO on top of helping people learning a lot and having fun!!! :)

Comment: @KelliAnderson: I have edited my answer to take into account your point! ;-) and also David remark